# How to create and seed new torrent files for BitTorrent using transmisson client? (Issue)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bittorrent, transmission

I'm trying to create and seed a new torrent file. Assuming the file I wanna share using BitTorrent is `foobar.tar` and the tracker that I've used is `udp://tracker.eddie4.nl:6969/announce`, which I got it from [here](https://fossbytes.com/torrent-trackers-list/). I've followed the following steps:

###### Creating a new torrent file:

`$ transmisson-create foobar.tar -t udp://tracker.eddie4.nl:6969/announce -o foobar.torrent foobar.tar`

###### Seeding the torrent that I've *just* created:

`$ transmisson-remote --add foobar.torrent`

But, after issuing the 2nd command—seeding step—I noticed the "Status" of the seeding torrent remains "Idle".

```bsh
$ transmisson-remote -l
ID     Done       Have  ETA           Up    Down  Ratio  Status       Name
   2*    0%       None  Unknown      0.0     0.0   None  Idle         foobar.tar
Sum:              None               0.0     0.0
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't seed. It'd be appreciated if someone could assist me in fixing this issue. The goal is to create and seed a torrent for sharing a file, like `foobar.tar`, from my server to other users—such that they can grab the `foobar.torrent` file to download `foobar.tar`. I'm not obligated to use transmission client, so feel free to recommend some other CLI clients, but I'll be doing everything from a remote server.

Comment: You could use the [OpenBitTorrent tracker](http://openbittorrent.com/). Question: Did you install `transmission-daemon`?

Comment: Is anyone attempting to download your new torrent?

Comment: @harrymc: I've tried using OpenBitTorrent tracker with `transmission-create -t udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:6969`, but it same result, doesn't work either. Yes, I have `transmissoin-daemon` installed. @Andread: No. I've tried to download it on my server, but I did try using it on my local machine but doesn't work either, it says idle.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've solved it. It turns out, I was trying to seed the wrong directory.

My `transmisson-remote`'s downloads gets stored at `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads`. So, I have to move my `foobar.tar` to the said directory and repeat the same procedure again; this time, it seeds.

Hope it'd help future users.